How to filter GET query Blazor-Server web app for a small number of records from a million rows table
I have a C# Blazor server web app with Entity Framework Core + a SQL Server database. I need to have a number of fetch/GET filters and want to know the best way to code them in C# and in T-SQL. The database table can have multi-million rows. When we ask for filtered data from this table, we expect no more than 500 rows to be returned.
I am looking for the best / fastest way to get the data returned to the user's browser page -- either using a C# query similar to this one...
// Filter query for the customer.
IEnumerable<Table1> getQuery =
      from recs in _dbContext.Table1()
      where (recs.UID_CUSTOMER == pUID_CUSTOMER)
      select recs;

// Fetch the data 
return getQuery.ToList();

Or...from using stored-procedures in this example.
int customerUID = 7;
FormattableString uspCommand = $"EXEC {storedProcName} @CustomerUID = {customerUID}";

returnValue = _dbContext.Table1.FromSqlInterpolated(sqlCommand).ToList();

Which is a better way?

In general, a properly parametrized SQL query (and EF Core does turn your Linq queries into properly parametrized T-SQL queries) and a stored procedure are really the same, when executing, after the execution plan has been devised initially. A stored procedure doesn't have any "magical" speed advantage here - but it's typically much harder to use from EF Core. Therefore, my recommendation would be to use proper Linq queries, and make sure your underlying database tables are properly indexed

The second method, if I'm not mistaken, is open to injection though. You aren't parameterising the parameters for the procedure, you appear to be injecting them.

Thom...Thanks for the response.  I thought the "FromSqlInterpolated" sentence cures the injection issue.  I have seen code where parameters are defined in a new()-object.  I can seek out an example and apply it to my code we see in this question.

Thank you @marc_s for your reply.  Has any of my code in this question show me performing a "parametrized T-SQL query" ?  I am not sure if the "query" code above is C# query or SQL-query.  If you can, please provide me with a valid query that you are referring to.  In C# if so.  Thank you.

FromSqlInterpolated only avoids injection if you are using FormattableString all the way. Not using string in the middle. Another option you haven't considered: using a stored procedure with a parameter @UID_CUSTOMER.

Thank you @Charlieface...I accept your comment regarding the FormattableString "all the way"...I will correct my code. Thx  Furthermore, I have considered the stored procedure passing UID_CUSTOMER, since that limits the number of rows specifically for that customer.  :-)      Then I can "filter" from that huge list, smaller than multi-million rows.  thanks.

Is there a specific reason why you are using FromSqlInterpolated  rather than creating an IQueryable request against a defined DbSet in the DbContext?

Fastest way within EF: Use projection to fetch just what you need from the entities.
This code is terrible:
IEnumerable<Table1> getQuery =
    from recs in await this.GetAllCustomers()
    where (recs.UID_CUSTOMER == pUID_CUSTOMER)
    select recs;

... when "GetAllCustomers()" is doing something like:
await _dbContext.Table1!.ToListAsync();

The above is loading ALL rows into memory.
Better would just be:
IEnumerable<Table1> getQuery = await _dbContext.Table1
    .Where (recs.UID_CUSTOMER == pUID_CUSTOMER)
    .ToListAsync();

This tells EF to generate an SQL query to only return the X number of rows you are interested in.
Even better would be to look at what fields from Table1 you need and compose a ViewModel with just those columns. For instance if the Table1 table consists of 50 columns but you only need 10, and/or there are values to be pulled from related tables then leveraging Select will have EF build an efficient SQL to fetch just the columns needed rather than pulling back all 50 columns and/or generating a Cartesian Product (eager loading) or a SELECT N+1 scenario (lazy loading)
IEnumerable<Table1ViewModel> getQuery = await _dbContext.Table1
    .Where (recs => recs.UID_CUSTOMER == pUID_CUSTOMER)
    .Select(recs => new Table1ViewModel
    {
        Id = recs.Id,
        Value1 = recs.Value1,
        // ...
    }).ToListAsync();

From here you can inspect index usage and optimize as needed. It is a good idea to design for sorting and pagination when fetching data to ensure users are getting the most relevant data first and avoiding land mines where "most" data should be a manageable volume, but some edge cases see big, slow result sets being pulled.
For read operations leverage projection. For update operations fetch entities since you will typically be reading individual rows by PK which is extremely fast.
